Error 503 Backend fetch failed. Guru Meditation: XID: xxxx Varnish cache server. OVH
My Drupal 10 website hosted on OVH. I recently tested the form (it's a Webform module) which includes a field for uploading a file, and clicked 'submit' button, an error appears on the page: Error 503 Backend fetch failed. Guru Meditation: XID: xxxx Varnish cache server.
It was working correctly in my local environment; I was able to submit the file without any issues. However, now that it's in production, when I test it, I encounter this error.
Anyone know what may be the cause or any ideas please?

The 503 error that says Guru Meditation is Varnish's way of saying that the backend didn't return the proper output.
Troubleshooting the guru meditation error
Have a look at the following tutorial to learn how to debug this error and find the root cause: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/troubleshooting-varnish/#the-guru-meditation-error.
As mentioned in https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/troubleshooting-varnish/#backend-errors, you can run the following command to figure out what's going on:
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "VCL_call eq 'BACKEND_ERROR'"

Inspecting health probes
If we already assume that the backend is unavailable and you set a .probe property in your backend definition, you can run the following command to inspect the health checks:
sudo varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health

Generic log inspection
If the specific varnishlog commands didn't provide the insight you needed, you can run a pretty generic command to catch all the logs.
The problem is the verbosity of these logs, so maybe we should add a filter based on the URL. The following example will filter the logs for the homepage:
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"

Run this command if the problem occurs on the homepage.
If the output doesn't make sense, go ahead and add it to your question as pre-formated code. I'll help you troubleshoot.
